# MySQL ODBC Connector Sometimes Fails to connect to my AWS RDS Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-rds, mysql-connector

I have a mysql 8.0 server on AWS RDS, and I have an MS Access application that connects through MySQL ODBC driver to this server.

Everything has been fine for nearly a year now, but suddenly in the last week, the ODBC driver sometimes just.. doesn't connect. It just acts like the hostname is doesn't exist and throws an error when I try to test the ODBC connection.

"Connection failed with the following error: Unknown MySQL server host ''"

The strange part is that its intermittent. I know the hostname, user, password, and port are all correct. I've checked the RDS instance and we're not using up excessive resources. The firewall is open as much as it should be, and I've tried making it completely open temporarily just to see if that made a difference.

I've also tried connecting to the server through the MySQL SHELL, and through MySQL Workbench, and it also sometimes fails. However if I attempt to connect through BASH or windows command line, it connects fine 100% of the time. Unfortunately that's not useful to me as the application is setup to use ODBC and I am unable to change it at this stage.

I'm almost positive there is an issue with my RDS instance, as I've tried changing ODBC Driver versions, different computers, everything. But everything there looks fine too so I'm at a loss.

Comment: To me this sounds like a dns lookup issue.

Comment: @Shadow how would I diagnose that?

Comment: There are lot of tools you can download from the Internet that can capture packets and test dns lookups. Find one you like based on your operating system and network infrastrcuture.